# How to calculate weight matrix of Hamiltonian for logic gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, hamiltonian-simulation

How can we find the $J$ matrix representing a logic gate truth table?

$$H=-\sum_i h_im_i-\sum_{i\lt j}J_{ij}m_im_j,$$

with

$$J=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & +2 \\-1 & 0 & +2\\+2 & +2 &0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

See, Camsari, K. Y., Faria, R., Sutton, B. M., & Datta, S. (2017). Stochastic  p -Bits for Invertible Logic. Physical Review X, 7(3). https://doi.org/10.1103/physrevx.7.031014

Comment: Welcome to QCSE. Your equations are small, you could try to take your time to rewrite them using mathjax, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Could you add more information to your question? So far, it seems you want everyone to read the paper or know the context of already.